# how to delete entry from root cron which is already existing not created through chef cron resource

Tags: ruby, cron, chef-infra

My `cron` entry :

```
[root@server1 ~]# cat /var/spool/cron/root
0 21 * * * /bin/bash -c "sleep $[RANDOM \% 60 + 1]m"; nice -n 10 /opt/snow/snowagent -w /opt/snow/ >/dev/null 2>&1
# Chef Name: account_lister_clean
0 12,23 * * * rm -f /opt/scripts/acct_list_run_once
# Chef Name: logger_cron
0 0 * * * /opt/unx_logger.sh
```

========================================

I wanted to delete the below line alone using chef .

```
0 21 * * * /bin/bash -c "sleep $[RANDOM \% 60 + 1]m"; nice -n 10 /opt/snow/snowagent -w /opt/snow/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

=========================================

```
delete_lines 'remove snow agent cron at 22:00' do
        path '/var/spool/cron/root'
        pattern '^*/opt/snow/snowagent'
end
```

Im getting error as given below ,  what would be the pattern especially it has to delete the `/opt/snow/snowagen`t which starts at 22:00 only because we are creating same `cron` starts at 04:00 . I dont want to delete which runs at 04:00 .

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `delete_lines' for cookbook: test_lnx_slm9upgrade, recipe: install_slm9 :Chef::Recipe
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have `delete_lines`, could be that you missed importing it.

Meanwhile I found you a simple solution to do it

```rb
ruby_block 'remove snow agent' do
  block do
    rc = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/etc/hosts')
    rc.search_file_delete_line(/\/opt\/snow\/snowagent/, '')
    rc.write_file
  end
end
```

You can find more information on this at https://rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Util/FileEdit#search_file_delete_line-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

The `delete_lines` resource you are trying to use comes from [line](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/line) cookbook. Most probably you have not added dependency for the cookbook in your cookbook's metadata.

You'll need to:

1. Make sure this cookbook is available on your Chef server, or locally if you are running Chef in local mode. The instructions to get this cookbook are available in the page linked above.
2. Add the dependency for this cookbook in your cookbook's metadata. In your cookbook directory edit the `metadata.rb` file and add the below entry:

   ```rb
   depends 'line'
   ```

In my testing, I was able to remove the line with below code:

```rb
delete_lines 'remove snow agent cron at 22:00' do
  path '/var/spool/cron/root'
  pattern '^.*/opt/snow/snowagent'
end
```